# Reading Java properties files in Hadoop MapReduce applications

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I was wondering what is the standard practice for reading Java properties files in MapReduce applications and how to pass the location to it when submitting (starting) a job. 
In regular Java applications you can pass the location to the properties file as a JVM system property (-D) or argument to main method.
What is the best alternative (standard practice) for this for MapReduce jobs? Some good examples would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best alternative is to use `DistributedCache`, however it may not be the standard way. There can be other ways. But I haven't seen any code using anything else so far.

The idea is to add the file to the cache, and read it inside `setup` method of map/reduce and load values into a `Properties` or a `Map`. If you need snippet I can add.

Oh I can remember, my friend [**JtheRocker**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/633970/ssaikia-jtherocker) used another approach. He set entire contents of the file against a key in the `Configuration` object, got it's value on `setup` then parsing & loading the pairs in a `Map`. In this case, file reading is done on the driver, which was previously on the task's side. While it's suitable for small files and seems cleaner, orthodox people may not like to pollute `conf` at all.

I would like to see, what other posts bring out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This seems to be a good approach. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems that you still need to hardcode the location of the file, so you can add it to the DistributedCache. Do you know if there is any workaround for this?

Comment: u'll add the propFilePath to cache in the driver, so just pass it as a command line argument, no need to hardcode. Now do something like `conf.set("my.prop.file.name", new Path(propFilePath).getName().toString)` to get the filename in map/reduce against the key `my.prop.file.name` which u must have   to hardcode.

Comment: Thanks! This is the best approach I have seen so far.

Comment: When trying to implement this solution, I noticed that DistributedCache is deprecated in the current version of Hadoop. I read about some alternatives like job.addCacheFile which might work as well, so I'm going to try it out.